# Move a 2D character in Unity with UI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Character Object is a collection of sprites and with two animations and  a script, I control the movement with the default keys from the Keyboard.

Character GameObject:

[image]

I have my UI Button and i am trying to call the function that handles the movement inside the script that its attached to the Character `GameObject`, but the problems is in `OnClick()` that does not show the function. The function in the script is the `void FixedUpdate()` but when i am in the `OnClick()`, does not show the `FixedUpdate` Function. The `FixedUpdate()` contains the horizontal movement of the character and the Update() contains the characters jump instruction modifying the `rigidbody2D` parameters.

UI Button function selection:

[image]

If I add an trigger event to the UI Button, it happens the same thing, does not show the `FixedUpdate()` function.

I want to know if there is any other way to attach the movement of my character to the UI Buttons or if I am doing something wrong.

PD:(C# Code)

Answer (score 0):

`FixedUpdate()` is a default Monobehavior function (that you can override) and will not show up in the button's onClick options in the inspector. This also applies for other default Monobehavior functions (Start, Update, OnTriggerEnter, etc) that you can override.

Since you already have most of your code implemented in `FixedUpdate()`, I suggest modifying it slightly this way:

```
private bool toMoveRight = false;

...

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (toMoveRight)
    {
        // YOUR EXISTING LOGIC HERE
        //...
        toMoveRight = false;
    }
}

....

public void MoveRight()
{
    toMoveRight = true;
}

//USE SIMILAR FUNCTIONS TO MOVE LEFT, JUMP, OTHER MOVEMENTS THAT YOU NEED
```

You can now find `MoveRight()` (and any other similar functions that you implement) in the drop-down for the button's onClick in the inspector.

I am assuming you want your character to move/take action immediately and once on pushing the button. If you want the buttons to work as toggle-buttons, you will need to modify the code slightly.

I hope that helps!